# Process.Kill non-static field error

Tags: c#, error-handling, non-static

I want to read in information with an .exe file into another script. 
Afterwards, this .exe file can be closed immediately.

I use the following code:

```
  static void CallFile()
  {
     Process.Start(File.exe);
     Process.Kill();
  }
```

I have found on several sites that these are the best/easiest commands to use in order to open and close a specific file. However, I have the following error with my process.kill:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Process.Kill()'
```

It is in a function that is static
Normally adding the word `static` solves this error. However, this gives the error that the modifier `static`is not valid for this item. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint 1: you're trying to kill a process. *Which* process? How do you expect the statement `Process.Kill()` to know? Hint 2: The `Process.Start` method returns a reference to a `Process` object...

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
var p = Process.Start(File.exe);
p.Kill();
```

`p` is an *instance* of `Process`.  The error message you got is saying that you can't call an instance method on a class directly (i.e. `Process`); you have to call it on an *instance of that class*.  The needed "object reference' the error refers to would be, for example, `p`.

Think about it this way: it doesn't make sense for you to be able to call `Process.Kill();` directly -- i.e. if it *were* a static method instead of an instance method; what process would you be targeting by that call?  You have potentially hundreds of processes running; it's not going to just assume it was the last one you started (e.g. via `Process.Start(File.exe);`).

Comment: also, you might need to wait the File.exe finish?

Comment: @roryap Thank you very much for this answer! It solved my problem, and more importantly, I understand what I did wrong with my code:)

Comment: @urlreader Yeah that is the next thing I want to check, what time it takes to let the other program finish. But that's probably gonna be a trial and error:)